# Просмотр карты в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity3d. Есть UI Image - карта. Большая карта. Её нужно увеличивать скроллом и двигать её курсором. Как это сделать на С#?

Comment: Может колёсиком увеличивать?

Answer (score 1):

У камеры есть field of view, берешь scrolldelta с мышки через input, задаешь скорость,  например 10, умножаешь на эту delta и прибавляешь к field of view.

С передвижением, получаешь позицию мышки через input в момент нажатия, запоминаешь как базовую, потом пока мышка нажата берешь ее позицию каждый кадр, отнимаешь от новой позиции базовую, получаешь направление, смещаешь свой image на это направление.

Единственное надо учесть границы карты. Дальше сам)